# Pinescript compilation error of version5 If variables

Tags: compiler-errors, pine-script-v5

compilation error line 27 no viable alternative at input 'if' . Try to add line "//@version2 to the top of your script.

I have exhausted my means to correct this script any suggestions?

```
//@version=5
// This script is an example of a simple strategy that buys on a long entry signal
// and sells on a short entry signal. It uses the built-in long_entry and short_entry
// signals provided by TradingView.


// Load data for the S&P 500 ETF and apply the strategy
symbol("SPY", daily)
strategy("SPY Daily Trade")

// Define input variables
emaLength = input(title="EMA Length:", type=integer, defval=50)
stopLoss = input(title="Stop Loss:", type=float, defval=0.05)
takeProfit = input(title="Take Profit:", type=float, defval=0.1)

// Calculate the exponential moving average
ema = ema(close, emaLength)

// Plot the exponential moving average
plot(ema, color=blue)

// Buy when the stock price crosses above the EMA
buyCondition = crossover(close, ema)

// Sell when the stock price crosses below the EMA
sellCondition = crossunder(close, ema) 

// Set stop loss and take profit levels
stopLossLevel = close * (1 - stopLoss)
takeProfitLevel = close * (1 + takeProfit)

// Enter a long position if the buy condition is met
if buyCondition 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=stopLossLevel, limit=takeProfitLevel)

// Enter a short position if the sell condition is met
if sellCondition
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, stop=takeProfitLevel, limit=stopLossLevel)

// Close the position if the opposite condition is met
if strategy.position_size != 0 and (buyCondition or sellCondition)
    strategy.close()
```

I tried correcting the if with supporting than statements. I also removed the declared variable and wrote it out with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close buddy -

A few points:

- I've changed some code to meet Pine v5 specs
- You don't need to include symbol info, just use the ticker and timeframe you want
- I've changed your SL/TP `inputs` so you can enter a % value rather than decimal value
- You need a SL/TP for both Long and Short trades (that's 4 values in total)
- These SL/TP values should be calculated from `strategy.position_avg_price` rather than `close` - The problem with `close` is it will get updated on every new bar!
- Updated your `strategy.exit` functions to suit

I hope this all helps

For more info on Stop Loss and Take Profits check out some code I've written on Tradingview..

https://www.tradingview.com/script/00WHGEoc-Fixed-Percent-Stop-Loss-Take-Profit/
https://www.tradingview.com/script/bVkqAx0s-Percent-Trailing-Stop/

I've also written some code for creating SL/TP & Trailing tops within Study scripts (now called Indicator scripts) :)

```
//@version=5

//JUST ADD THIS STRATEGY TO YOUR CHART LAYOUT WITH APPROPRIATE TICKER AND TIMEFRAME
//symbol("SPY", daily)??
strategy("SPY Daily Trade", overlay=true)

// Define input variables
emaLength = input.int(title="EMA Length:", defval=50)
stopLoss = input.float(title="Stop Loss %:", defval=5) / 100
takeProfit = input.float(title="Take Profit %:", defval=5) / 100

// Calculate the exponential moving average
ema = ta.ema(close, emaLength)

// Plot the exponential moving average
plot(ema, color=color.blue)

// Buy when the stock price crosses above the EMA
buyCondition = ta.crossover(close, ema)

// Sell when the stock price crosses below the EMA
sellCondition = ta.crossunder(close, ema) 

// Set stop loss and take profit levels
longStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopLoss)
shortStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + stopLoss)
shortTake = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - takeProfit)
longTake = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takeProfit)

// Enter a long position if the buy condition is met
if buyCondition 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

// Enter a short position if the sell condition is met
if sellCondition
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

// Close the position if the opposite condition is met
if strategy.position_size > 0 
    strategy.exit(id="Close Long", stop=longStop, limit=longTake)
if strategy.position_size < 0 
    strategy.exit(id="Close Short", stop=shortStop, limit=shortTake)
```

Comment: Thank you so  much ! This  makes sense now, and you have great examples. This did trick and is functioning as it should now.